# Facebook iOS SDK 3.2.1 Blank Dialog When Authorizing / Confirming Authorization

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk, dialog

I am building an app that needs to be iOS 5.0 compatible, so I need to include the Facebook SDK (v3.2.1) in order to publish photos to a user's photos.

I have setup the app in Facebook with all the correct info (id,bundle, etc.), set the URL scheme correctly in the plist (see below screenshot) and the app loads the permission dialog fine and shows my app image, etc.

**Simulator Results:**
Shows the dialog just fine, but then gives an alert when pressing 'OK' that "Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid'.

**Device Results (iPad):**
Opens Facebook native app and shows a dialog box, but its blank. Reading other forums I saw there is a bug with already authorized apps, so I removed the app from my Facebook settings on the device and try again. This time it loads the dialog ok, but then does nothing when I click 'OK'.

Ideas?

And yes, I am including this code (*note - the NSLog never gets called):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
    NSLog(@"Facebook Open URL");
    return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

**Plist Screenshot:**
[image]

Comment: show the code which you use to log in.

Answer (score 0):

First check the .plist file you have edited.
Chances are if you created project with unit test cases checked there will be another .plist file in you project. So if you modify that .plist safari wont redirect back to you app after authorizing. This is just a basic suggestion as I already faced this issue.

Comment: Yeah that wasn't the issue. Only have one plist, no unit tests enabled.

Answer (score 0):

check the .plist file , plist safari it might have a solution